# AngularJS TypeScript Kendo UI DropDownList - bug with default value selected

Tags: angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui, dropdown, default-selected

I have list of objects for items and everything works fine, but now I want to add **default value selected**, but I have issues with it.

Here's the HTML code for the drop-down:

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list 
        k-options="selectItems" 
        k-ng-model="selectedItem">
</select>
```

And in AngularJS (using TypeScript) I'm making the drop-down:

```
this.itemsToSelect = [{id: 1, name: "One"}, {id: 2, name: "Two"}];

this.selectItems = {
    optionLabel: "Select items...",
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: (options) => {
          options.success(this.itemsToSelect);
        }
      }
    }),
    value: this.itemsToSelect[0]
  };
```

I don't have default value selected with this.

I tried the code from their documentation and it works with items as strings, but with items as objects works when I say something like:

```
value: this.itemsToSelect[0].id
```

So, their code looks like this:

```
<script>
    let items = [{id: 1, name: "one"}, {id: 2, name: "two"}];

    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataValueField: "id",
        dataSource: items,
        value: items[1].id
    });
</script>
```

I tried this in my code and it doesn't work.

Code doesn't have any errors. Any suggestions?

> EDIT

What I can do is this:

```
this.selectedItem = this.itemsToSelect[0];
```

I've set `k-ng-model` in the HTML and I can just set the selected value like this.

But, is there a way to do it through **value** in `this.selectItems` object?

Answer (score 0):

Make a local object representing your default value, like

```
{ 
id: 1,
name: "bob"
}
```

then on the control set autoBind to false.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/configuration/autobind

Comment: it didn't make any difference, still giving me blank drop-down for default